# Get the second highest value in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table of employees and salaries defined that way:

```
"name" (type: VARCHAR)
"salary" (type: INTEGER)
```

What query can I use to get the second highest salary in this table?

Comment: What if you have 2 or more names with the same highest or 2nd highest salary?

Comment: @Pentium - I wondered the same...answered accordingly

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here's one that accounts for ties.

```
Name    Salary
Jim       6
Foo       5
Bar       5
Steve     4

SELECT name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees))

Result --> Bar 5, Foo 5
```

**EDIT:**
I took Manoj's second post, tweaked it, and made it a little more human readable. To me ***n-1*** is not intuitive; however, using the value I want, 2=2nd, 3=3rd, etc. is.

```
/* looking for 2nd highest salary -- notice the '=2' */
SELECT name,salary FROM employees
WHERE salary = (SELECT DISTINCT(salary) FROM employees as e1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(salary))=2 FROM employees as e2
WHERE e1.salary <= e2.salary)) ORDER BY name

Result --> Bar 5, Foo 5
```

Comment: What shall i do if i want to select thrird highest in from my table...Thanks in advance

Comment: SELECT name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees))). This technique is just nesting SELECT statements to the point at which you're trying to find a number (2nd, 3rd, 4th highest paid). If I wanted to find the 5th highest paid employee AND account for ties, I would add an additional 3 more SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees WHERE salary < ... etc. to the original answer's code.

Comment: Wow.Amazing this query give  exact result

Answer (score 54):

A straight forward answer for second highest salary

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM employees ORDER BY `employees`.`salary` DESC LIMIT 1 , 1
```

another interesting solution

```
SELECT salary 
FROM emp 
WHERE salary = (SELECT DISTINCT(salary) 
                FROM emp as e1 
                WHERE (n) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(salary)) 
                             FROM emp as e2 
                             WHERE e1.salary <= e2.salary))
```

Comment: Why is this getting up-voted? That SELECT statement only returns one value: the TOP Salary. The question was to find the 2nd highest salary.

Comment: This answer is getting up-voted because the first solution is the most straightforward solution. See the section on "offset" in the [MySQL docs on SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html). The first number after "LIMIT" is the offset when using the comma. The offset is zero-indexed. So, this query selects one row, starting at the second-highest. (though, this does not account for ties)

Comment: @Jon - check his edit. What it was doing in June, is NOT what it was doing in December.

Comment: Actually, your first query wont get accurate results. Consider the situation where more than one employee with second highest salary. Your query will return only one row.

Comment: 1st query won't work if more than 1 employee has the same highest salary or the same 2nd highest salary.

Answer (score 24):

Seems I'm much late to answer this question. How about this one liner to get the same output?

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1 ;
```

> sample fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v4gZUMFbuYorB27AH9yBKy/0

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is redundant here as the limit is already set to 1.

Comment: DISTINCT is not redundant. It is required as there may be two similar salaries one after other.

Comment: Even if we have duplicate salaries still we will get only one row as the `limit` is defined as 1. So the `limit` makes the size as one row only so the `DISTINCT` becomes redundant.

Comment: I think you just have started, check out this sample fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v4gZUMFbuYorB27AH9yBKy/0 the second query "without `DISTINCT`" returns wrong value.

Comment: Got your point now. Thanks a lot for the fiddle and the explanation.

Answer (score 9):

```
create table svalue (
name varchar(5),
value int
) engine = myisam;

insert into svalue value ('aaa',30),('bbb',10),('ccc',30),('ddd',20);

select * from svalue where value = (
select value 
from svalue
group by value
order by  value desc limit 1,1)
```

Answer (score 4):

FOR SECOND LAST:

```
SELECT name, salary
    FROM employee 
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    LIMIT 1 , 1
```

FOR THIRD LAST:

```
SELECT name, salary
    FROM employee 
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    LIMIT 2 , 1
```

Comment: What if you have 2 or more names with the same highest or 2nd highest salary?
Your solution would not work.
You have to either use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` And update your query

Answer (score 4):

You can use this below mentioned query

```
SELECT emp.name, emp.salary 
FROM employees emp 
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) 
           FROM employees 
           WHERE emp.salary<=salary
          );
```

You can change 2 to your desired highest record.

Answer (score 3):

To display records having second largest value of mark:

```
SELECT username, mark
FROM tbl_one
WHERE mark = (
    SELECT DISTINCT mark
    FROM tbl_one
    ORDER by mark desc
    LIMIT 1,1
);
```

Answer (score 3):

simple solution

```
SELECT * FROM TBLNAME ORDER BY COLNAME ASC LIMIT (n - x), 1
```

Note: n = total number of records in column

```
  x = value 2nd, 3rd, 4th highest etc
```

e.g

```
//to find employee with 7th highest salary

n = 100
x = 7

SELECT * FROM tbl_employee ORDER BY salary ASC LIMIT 93, 1
```

hope this helps

Comment: What if you have 2 or more names with the same highest or 2nd highest salary?
Your solution would not work.
You have to either use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` And update your query

Answer (score 3):

Found another interesting solution

```
SELECT salary 
FROM emp 
WHERE salary = (SELECT DISTINCT(salary) 
                FROM emp as e1 
                WHERE (n) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(salary)) 
                             FROM emp as e2 
                             WHERE e1.salary <= e2.salary))
```

Sorry. Forgot to write. n is the nth number of salary which you want.

Comment: SELECT salary FROM emp WHERE salary = (SELECT DISTINCT(salary) FROM emp as e1 WHERE (n) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(salary)) FROM emp as e2 WHERE e1.salary <= e2.salary)). Thsi will be the direct "n" substitution solution

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Salary
FROM emp
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1 , 1
```

This query will give second highest salary of the duplicate records as well.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution is as given below in query:

```
select max(salary) as salary from employees where salary<(select max(salary) from employees);
```

Answer (score 2):

for 2nd heightest salary

```
 select max(salary) from salary where salary not in (select top 1 salary from salary order by salary desc)
```

for 3rd heightest salary

```
 select max(salary) from salary where salary not in (select top 2 salary from salary order by salary desc)
```

and so on......

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MAX(salary) salary
FROM tbl
WHERE salary <
  (SELECT MAX(salary)
   FROM tbl);
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the **N**th highest value, better to use this solution:

```
SELECT * FROM `employees`  WHERE salary =
         (SELECT DISTINCT(salary) FROM `employees` 
         ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT {N-1},1);
```

or you can try with:

```
SELECT * FROM `employees` e1 WHERE 
        (N-1) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(salary)) 
        FROM `employees` e2 
        WHERE e1.salary < e2.salary );
```

N=2 for second highest 
N=3 for third highest and so on.

Answer (score 2):

To get the second highest salary just use the below query

```
SELECT salary FROM employees
ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1;
```

Comment: What if you have 2 or more names with the same highest or 2nd highest salary?
Your solution would not work.
You have to either use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` And update your query

Answer (score 2):

To get second highest value:

```
SELECT `salary` FROM `employees` ORDER BY `salary` DESC LIMIT 1, 1;
```

Comment: What if you have 2 or more names with the same highest or 2nd highest salary?
Your solution would not work.
You have to either use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` And update your query

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, salary 
FROM employees 
where
 salary = (SELECT (salary) FROM employees GROUP BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(id) as id FROM students where id>(SELECT MIN(id) FROM students);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to get n th max salary

i have tried this before posting & It Works fine

eg. to find 10th max salary replace **limit 9,1**;

`mysql> select name,salary from emp group by salary desc limit n-1,1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SALARY 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM EMPLOYEE 
      ORDER BY SALARY 
      DESC LIMIT ***2***) AS TOP_SALARY 
ORDER BY SALARY ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE salary = ( 
SELECT DISTINCT salary
FROM EMPLOYEES
ORDER BY salary DESC 
LIMIT 1 , 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with alias as
(
select name,salary,row_number() over(order by salary desc ) as rn from employees
)
select name,salary from alias where rn=n--n being the nth highest salary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username, salary
FROM tblname
GROUP by salary
ORDER by salary desc
LIMIT 0,1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM employees
order by salary desc limit 1,1
```

and this query should do your job.
First we are sorting the table in descending way so the person with the highest salary is at the top, and the second highest is at the second position. Now `limit a,b` means skip the starting `a` elements and then print the next `b` elements. So you should use `limit 1,1` in this case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,salary FROM employee
WHERE salary = (SELECT DISTINCT(salary) FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1) ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`salary`)
    FROM `employee`

    ORDER BY `salary` DEC
    LIMIT 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Get second, third, fourth......Nth highest salary using following query

```
SELECT MIN(salary) from employees WHERE salary IN( SELECT TOP N salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC)
```

Replace N by you number i.e. N=2 for second highest salary,
N=3 for third highest salary and so on. So for second highest salary use

```
SELECT MIN(salary) from employees WHERE salary IN( SELECT TOP 2 salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

`select MIN(salary) from employee order by age desc limit 2;`
It sorts the column in descending order takes the top 2 and returns the minimum of them which is the second highest.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
Proc sql;
  select employee, salary
  from (select * from test having salary < max(salary)) 
   having salary = max(salary)
  ;
Quit;
```

Comment: This is a very confusing answer - can you clarify a bit?

Comment: for the 2nd Maximum, remove the maximum from table using nested query. then the table generated from nested query get fed to outer query where marks should be equal to max(marks), Mind to add group by statement to see department wise 2nd maximum.

Comment: The field names don't even match the ones that were given in the question. It's possible there's a useful answer here, but if there is, then the OP should [edit] the answer to (a) clean up the sample code to reflect the given problem and (b) incorporate the explanatory text that's currently only in a comment.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I hoped discussing the logic would work. Anyway I have posted the code here. It returns the 2nd highest salary from table.