# mysql - Get two greatest values from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

We can use [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) to get greatest value from multiple columns like below

```
SELECT GREATEST(mark1,mark2,mark3,mark4,mark5) AS best_mark FROM marks
```

But now I want to get two best marks from all(5) marks.

Can I do this on mysql query?

Table structure (I know it is wrong - created by someone):

```
student_id  | Name | mark1 | mark2 | mark3 | mark4 | mark5
```

Comment: What is your table structure

Comment: @Jake1164 query explains just about everything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360894/get-the-second-highest-value-in-a-mysql-table

Comment: @AndyThompson it's different question.

Comment: @jWeavers - Sorry, I thought he wanted the top2 for each of mark1-5 not the best out of the five.

Comment: Consider normalizing your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution but if you cannot alter the table structure then you can *unpivot* the data and then apply a user defined variable to get a row number for each student_id.  The code will be similar to the following:

```
select student_id, name, col, data
from
(
  SELECT student_id, name, col,
    data,
    @rn:=case when student_id = @prev then @rn else 0 end +1 rn,
    @prev:=student_id
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT student_id, name, col,
      @rn, 
      @prev,
      CASE s.col
        WHEN 'mark1' THEN mark1
        WHEN 'mark2' THEN mark2
        WHEN 'mark3' THEN mark3
        WHEN 'mark4' THEN mark4
        WHEN 'mark5' THEN mark5
      END AS DATA
    FROM marks
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
      SELECT 'mark1' AS col UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'mark2' UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'mark3' UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'mark4' UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'mark5'
    ) s
    cross join (select @rn := 0, @prev:=0) c
  ) s
  order by student_id, data desc
) d
where rn <= 2
order by student_id, data desc;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1dd1/20). This will return the top 2 marks per `student_id`. The inner subquery is performing a similar function as using a UNION ALL to unpivot but you are not querying against the table multiple times to get the result.

Comment: I think OP wanted to create a column out of ALL the 5 mark columns, and then pick out the 2 highest ones. Not sure though. My solution reflects this anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change your database structure, because having that many marks horizontally (i.e. as fields/columns) already means you're doing something wrong.

Instead put all your marks in a separate table where you create a many to many relationship and then perform the necessary `SELECT` together with `LIMIT`.

Suggestions:

1. Create a table that you call `mark_types`. Columns: `id`, `mark_type`. I
   see that you currently have 5 type of marks; it would be very simple
   to add additional types.
2. Change your `marks` table to hold 3 columns: `id`,
   `mark`/`grade`/`value`, `mark_type` (this column foreign constraints to
   `mark_types`).
3. Write your `SELECT` query with the help of joins, and `GROUP BY mark_type`.

Comment: table structure created by some one so I don't want to interfere on that just I need solution for current table structure.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a temporary table and then

[Create a temporary table in a SELECT statement without a separate CREATE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-temporary-table-from-select-statement-without-using-create-table)

query that table as follows

SELECT TOP 2 * FROM temp
ORDER BY mark DESC

then

drop temp table

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's a new answer that's should work with the current table structure:

```
SELECT `student_id`, `Name`, `mark` FROM (SELECT `student_id`, `Name`, `mark1` AS `mark` FROM `marks`
                                          UNION ALL
                                          SELECT `student_id`, `Name`, `mark2` AS `mark` FROM `marks`
                                          UNION ALL
                                          SELECT `student_id`, `Name`, `mark3` AS `mark` FROM `marks`
                                          UNION ALL
                                          SELECT `student_id`, `Name`, `mark4` AS `mark` FROM `marks`
                                          UNION ALL
                                          SELECT `student_id`, `Name`, `mark5` AS `mark` FROM `marks`) AS `marks`
ORDER BY `mark` DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: you should also include `student_id` and `name` otherwise.. it won't show correct output.