# Getting second highest Salary value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

In a given question,

> Write a SQL query to get the second highest salary from the Employee table.

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

> For example, given the above Employee table, the query should return 200 as the second highest salary. **If there is no second highest salary, then the query should return null.**

```
+---------------------+
| SecondHighestSalary |
+---------------------+
| 200                 |
+---------------------+
```

---

I wrote a code for this question, however, the expected output is different.

My Code:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN NULL
    ELSE (SELECT Salary FROM Employee HAVING Salary < MAX(Salary) ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1)
END AS SecondHighestSalary
FROM Employee;
```

I think there's something wrong with my code but I cannot find what is the actual problem here. My code returns `100` not `200`. What have I gotten wrong?

```
+---------------------+
| SecondHighestSalary |
+---------------------+
| 100                 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: You can get nth highest record visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/26732513/2893413

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize `LIMIT {[offset,] row_count}`. Refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Order by `Salary` in descending order, and get the second row by defining `OFFSET` as 1. We will use `DISTINCT` on `Salary` as there is a possibility to have multiple rows for the highest salary.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Salary
FROM Employee
ORDER BY Salary DESC
LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: @Sadikhasan how does it even matter, as OP only wants the salary figure, not the full row.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I tried this and this does not return `null` when there's only one employee. I think maybe adding `IFNULL()` would do?

Comment: @Poream3387 hmm.. let me test. I havent tested it.

Comment: @Poream3387 it returns no results: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e1Efjj6SY5xVrTEuJ9oP4j/0  - It is pretty much equivalent to getting `null`. You can handle this in application code (eg: PHP), when no rows are returned.

Comment: By wrapping the answer in a select you would be able to get "null" value if there is no second highest salary

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph it is unnecessary, when such basic things can be handled more efficiently in the application code. Why unnecessarily burden the MySQL server with a materialized subquery.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i agree with you on the burden part and also disagree--> nulls and no_rows_returned are not the same thing

Answer (score 2):

You can try below

```
SELECT MAX(salary) From Employee WHERE salary < ( SELECT Max(salary) FROM Employee);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that out:

```
SELECT salary FROM Employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

or to a deeper approach you can use something like:

```
SELECT salary FROM Employee GROUP BY salary ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

All that queries have high performance, since they does not have any subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a empty_row(null) in case there is no highest salary then the following does it, if there is a value then it gets shown

```
select (select salary
          from Employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1
        ) as x
```

Comment: The OP wanted to return a row with "null" value in case there is no second highest salary.. Without the "wrapper, the query would return "no_rows_returned" or an empty record set.

Comment: Right, got it!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
SELECT MAX(salary) From Employee WHERE salary < ( SELECT Max(salary) FROM Employee);
```