# How to get second Max value of mark list?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I used MAX function.

How to get the second highest maths mark from the database.

> e.g: (maths : 96 , 88 , 55);

```
SELECT MAX(maths) FROM mark;
```

how do I get 88 from SQL query?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want.

Comment: this question already asked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the second highest value in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360894/get-the-second-highest-value-in-a-mysql-table)

Comment: Thank you for repute answer @hardiksolanki

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest SQL Query to find the second largest value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100/what-is-the-simplest-sql-query-to-find-the-second-largest-value)

Comment: Thank you @SayedMohdAli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX( column ) FROM table WHERE column < ( SELECT MAX( column ) FROM table )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the second highest mark, you would use `limit`/`offset`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT maths
FROM mark
ORDER BY maths DESC
LIMIT 1, 1;
```

Comment: e.g: (maths : 96 , 88 , 55); how to I get 88 in the SQL query

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery to get the overall maximum and then get the maximum of those values less the overall maximum.

```
SELECT max(maths)
       FROM mark
       WHERE math < (SELECT max(maths)
                            FROM mark);
```

Answer (score 1):

select maths from mark order by maths desc limit 1 offset 1

Comment: e.g: (maths : 96 , 88 , 55);

how to I get 88 in the SQL query

Answer (score 1):

SELECT MAX( maths )
  FROM mark
 WHERE maths < ( SELECT MAX( maths )
                 FROM mark )

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 SELECT MAX(maths) FROM mark WHERE maths NOT IN ( SELECT Max(maths) FROM mark);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT mark
FROM testing
ORDER BY mark DESC
LIMIT 1, 1
```

And I just attached my table screen for your reference.

[image]