# Mysql get second max date limit 1 base on user id joining table log

Tags: mysql, join

I want to get second max login date from user_log table and returning login date to `null` when `user_id` records are not in `user_log` table and only single login date on `user_log` table.

for the example case.

**user_log CASE 1**

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════════════════════╗
║ ID      ║ USER_ID   ║ TYPE  ║  UPDATED_AT          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══════════════════════╣
║    1    ║ 1         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:00:00  ║
║    2    ║ 2         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:02:00  ║last login user_id 2
║    3    ║ 1         ║ Logout║ 2019-06-19 15:03:00  ║
║    5    ║ 1         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:04:00  ║last login user_id 1 
║    6    ║ 2         ║ Logout║ 2019-06-19 15:05:00  ║
║    7    ║ 3         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:06:00  ║last login user_id 3
║    8    ║ 2         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:07:00  ║
║    9    ║ 1         ║ Logout║ 2019-06-19 15:08:00  ║
║    10   ║ 1         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:10:00  ║
║    11   ║ 3         ║ Logout║ 2019-06-19 15:15:00  ║
║    12   ║ 3         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:18:00  ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════════════════════╝
```

**user_log CASE 2**

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════════════════════╗
║ ID      ║ USER_ID   ║ TYPE  ║  UPDATED_AT          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══════════════════════╣
║    1    ║ 1         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:00:00  ║last login user_id 1
║    2    ║ 1         ║ Logout║ 2019-06-19 15:03:00  ║
║    3    ║ 1         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:04:00  ║
║    4    ║ 2         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:05:00  ║
║    5    ║ 3         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:07:00  ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════════════════════╝
```

**user_log CASE 3**

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════════════════════╗
║ ID      ║ USER_ID   ║ TYPE  ║  UPDATED_AT          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══════════════════════╣
║    1    ║ 1         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:00:00  ║
║    2    ║ 2         ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:05:00  ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════════════════════╝
```

**table users**

```
╔═════════╦════════════╗
║ ID      ║  USERNAME  ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║    1    ║   XX       ║
║    2    ║   YY       ║
║    3    ║   ZZ       ║
╚═════════╩════════════╝
```

**This is my query.**

`SELECT u.id as iduser,u.username,ul.type,MAX(ul.updated_at) last_login_date
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_log ul ON u.id=ul.user_id
where ul.type = 'Login'
GROUP BY u.id`

this query is just showing the max login date and only when `user_id` record in `user_log` table

**Expected Result case 1**

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════════════════════╗
║ USER_ID   ║ USERNAME  ║ TYPE  ║  LAST_LOGIN_DATE     ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══════════════════════╣
║ 1         ║ XX        ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:04:00  ║LOG_ID(5)
║ 2         ║ YY        ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:02:00  ║LOG_ID(2)
║ 3         ║ ZZ        ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:06:00  ║LOG_ID(7)
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════════════════════╝
```

**Expected Result case 2**

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════════════════════╗
║ IDUSER    ║ USERNAME  ║ TYPE  ║  LAST_LOGIN_DATE     ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══════════════════════╣
║ 1         ║ XX        ║ Login ║ 2019-06-19 15:00:00  ║LOG_ID(1)
║ 2         ║ YY        ║ -     ║ -                    ║LOG_ID(-)
║ 3         ║ ZZ        ║ -     ║ -                    ║LOG_ID(-)
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════════════════════╝
```

**Expected Result case 3**

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════════════════════╗
║ USER_ID   ║ USERNAME  ║ TYPE  ║  LAST_LOGIN_DATE     ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══════════════════════╣
║ 1         ║ XX        ║ -     ║ -                    ║LOG_ID(-)
║ 2         ║ YY        ║ -     ║ -                    ║LOG_ID(-)
║ 3         ║ ZZ        ║ -     ║ -                    ║LOG_ID(-)
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════════════════════╝
```

all case should be one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have the following log entries for three users:

```
+----+---------+--------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | type   | updated_at          |
+----+---------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 | Login  | 2019-06-19 15:00:00 |
|  6 |       2 | Login  | 2019-06-19 15:02:00 |
|  2 |       1 | Logout | 2019-06-19 15:03:00 |
|  3 |       1 | Login  | 2019-06-19 15:04:00 |
|  7 |       2 | Logout | 2019-06-19 15:05:00 |
|  8 |       2 | Login  | 2019-06-19 15:07:00 |
|  4 |       1 | Logout | 2019-06-19 15:08:00 |
| 10 |       3 | Login  | 2019-06-19 15:09:00 |
|  5 |       1 | Login  | 2019-06-19 15:10:00 |
+----+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

Based on similar questions like [What is the simplest SQL Query to find the second largest value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100/what-is-the-simplest-sql-query-to-find-the-second-largest-value) or [Get the second highest value in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360894/get-the-second-highest-value-in-a-mysql-table) you can first create a `SELECT` query which returns the last `login` entry, which would be the current active session/login:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    MAX(updated_at) as max_updated
FROM
    user_log
WHERE
    type = 'Login'
GROUP BY
    user_id
```

This would give you the following result:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| user_id | max_updated         |
+---------+---------------------+
|       1 | 2019-06-19 15:10:00 |
|       2 | 2019-06-19 15:07:00 |
|       3 | 2019-06-19 15:09:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

You join this result on the `user_log` table again on the same user id.

```
SELECT
    a.user_id,
    a.type,
    a.updated_at,
    b.max_updated
FROM
    user_log a
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            user_id,
            MAX(updated_at) as max_updated
        FROM
            user_log
        WHERE
            type = 'Login'
        GROUP BY
            user_id
    ) b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
```

This will get you the following result:

```
+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id | type   | updated_at          | max_updated         |
+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       1 | Login  | 2019-06-19 15:00:00 | 2019-06-19 15:10:00 |
|       1 | Logout | 2019-06-19 15:03:00 | 2019-06-19 15:10:00 |
|       1 | Login  | 2019-06-19 15:04:00 | 2019-06-19 15:10:00 |
|       1 | Logout | 2019-06-19 15:08:00 | 2019-06-19 15:10:00 |
|       1 | Login  | 2019-06-19 15:10:00 | 2019-06-19 15:10:00 |
|       2 | Login  | 2019-06-19 15:02:00 | 2019-06-19 15:07:00 |
|       2 | Logout | 2019-06-19 15:05:00 | 2019-06-19 15:07:00 |
|       2 | Login  | 2019-06-19 15:07:00 | 2019-06-19 15:07:00 |
|       3 | Login  | 2019-06-19 15:09:00 | 2019-06-19 15:09:00 |
+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

You can use the `max_updated` column to remove any row where the `updated_at` column is the same. Such a row would be the "last" row, but since you don't want these rows (but instead all the previous rows), you filter them with a `WHERE` clause (and filter by the `type` as well).

```
SELECT
    a.user_id,
    a.type,
    a.updated_at,
    b.max_updated
FROM
    user_log a
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            user_id,
            MAX(updated_at) as max_updated
        FROM
            user_log
        WHERE
            type = 'Login'
        GROUP BY
            user_id
    ) b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE
    a.updated_at != b.max_updated AND
    type = 'Login'
```

This will get you the following:

```
+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id | type  | updated_at          | max_updated         |
+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       1 | Login | 2019-06-19 15:00:00 | 2019-06-19 15:10:00 |
|       1 | Login | 2019-06-19 15:04:00 | 2019-06-19 15:10:00 |
|       2 | Login | 2019-06-19 15:02:00 | 2019-06-19 15:07:00 |
+---------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

This looks promising as the row for the user `3` doesn't exists anymore, we have only `Login` entries and the login from the current/active session isn't selected. From here it is straight forward by using a `GROUP BY` and then a `LEFT JOIN` on the users table.

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.username,
    l.type,
    l.last_login_date
FROM
    users u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        a.user_id,
        a.type,
        MAX(a.updated_at) AS last_login_date
    FROM
        user_log a
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                user_id,
                MAX(updated_at) as max_updated
            FROM
                user_log
            WHERE
                type = 'Login'
            GROUP BY
                user_id
        ) b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
    WHERE
        a.updated_at != b.max_updated AND
        type = 'Login'
    GROUP BY
        a.user_id) l ON u.id = l.user_id
```

This will get you the following result:

```
+------+----------+-------+---------------------+
| id   | username | type  | last_login_date     |
+------+----------+-------+---------------------+
|    1 | XX       | Login | 2019-06-19 15:04:00 |
|    2 | YY       | Login | 2019-06-19 15:02:00 |
|    3 | ZZ       | NULL  | NULL                |
+------+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT date FROM tbl_date  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1,1;

you can use this query for getting second max date.

Comment: have you tried the code, and get the exact result so you post the answer?