# Return second highest date

Tags: mysql, sql, zoho

I have a sales table, where it shows the information below

| ID_sale | sales_person | sale_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 50 | 19/10/2022 |
| 6 | 43 | 17/9/2022 |
| 5 | 50 | 15/3/2022 |
| 4 | 43 | 13/2/2022 |
| 2 | 50 | 22/1/2022 |
| 3 | 10 | 05/2/2022 |
| 1 | 12 | 07/1/2022 |

and I want to create a query where I get the following information, basically the most recent date of the sale and the last sale date they made

| ID_sale | sales_person | recent_sale | last_sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 50 | 19/10/2022 | 15/3/2022 |
| 6 | 43 | 17/9/2022 | 13/2/2022 |
| 3 | 10 | 05/2/2022 | 05/2/2022 |
| 1 | 12 | 07/1/2022 | 07/1/2022 |

Thank you

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360894/get-the-second-highest-value-in-a-mysql-table

Comment: Is it really true that an earlier sale has a higher ID? Is ID_Sale an auto increment ID? If so , shouldn't it be greater for a later sale?

Comment: oh no I apologies, the most recent sales will have greater id

Comment: I would assume that your date format is actually according to MySQL date datatype format and the date values you've posted in your question is from other source.

Comment: @Kishko please edit your question to show realistic ID's for the rows (incrementing over time) and mention it's auto increment

Answer (score 1):

We use `rank()` to find the most recent couple of sales and then pivot the results.

```
select    max(recent_ID_sale)                         as ID_sale
         ,sales_person
         ,max(recent_sale)                            as recent_sale
         ,coalesce(max(last_sale), max(recent_sale))  as last_sale
from
(
select    sales_person
         ,case when rank() over(partition by sales_person order by sale_date desc) = 1 then sale_date end as recent_sale
         ,case when rank() over(partition by sales_person order by sale_date desc) = 2 then sale_date end as last_sale
         ,case when rank() over(partition by sales_person order by sale_date desc) = 1 then ID_sale   end as recent_ID_sale

from      t
) t
group by sales_person
order by recent_sale desc
```

| ID_sale | sales_person | recent_sale | last_sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2022-10-19 | 2022-03-15 |
| 2 | 43 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-02-13 |
| 6 | 10 | 2022-02-05 | 2022-02-05 |
| 7 | 12 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-01-07 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u_1GvIxp)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a CTE first where you add a row_nmber to get the order of the dates and then select them

## update

I added a solution without GROUP BY and further window functions at the end

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (ID_sale int, sales_person int, sale_date date)
;
    
INSERT INTO t
    (ID_sale, sales_person, sale_date)
VALUES
    (1, 50, '2022-10-19'),
    (2, 43, '2022-9-17'),
    (3, 50, '2022-3-15'),
    (4, 43, '2022-2-13'),
    (5, 50, '2022-1-22'),
    (6, 10, '2022-2-5'),
    (7, 12, '2022-1-7')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
WITH CTE AS 
 ( select 
  ID_sale, sales_person, sale_date,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sales_person ORDER BY sale_date DESC) rn
from   t)
 SELECT
  MIN(ID_sale), sales_person,
  (SELECT sale_date FROM CTE WHERE sales_person = c1.sales_person and  rn = 1) recent_sale ,
  COALESCE(
  (SELECT sale_date FROM CTE WHERE sales_person = c1.sales_person and  rn = 2),
  (SELECT sale_date FROM CTE WHERE sales_person = c1.sales_person and  rn = 1)) last_sale 
  FROM CTE c1
  GROUP BY sales_person
  ORDER BY recent_sale DESC;
```

| MIN(ID_sale) | sales_person | recent_sale | last_sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2022-10-19 | 2022-03-15 |
| 2 | 43 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-02-13 |
| 6 | 10 | 2022-02-05 | 2022-02-05 |
| 7 | 12 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-01-07 |

```
WITH CTE AS 
 ( select 
  ID_sale, sales_person, sale_date,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sales_person ORDER BY sale_date DESC) rn
from   t)
 SELECT
  ID_sale, sales_person,
  Sale_date  recent_sale ,
  COALESCE(
  (SELECT sale_date FROM CTE WHERE sales_person = c1.sales_person and  rn = 2),
  Sale_date) last_sale 
  FROM CTE c1
  WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY recent_sale DESC;
```

| ID_sale | sales_person | recent_sale | last_sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2022-10-19 | 2022-03-15 |
| 2 | 43 | 2022-09-17 | 2022-02-13 |
| 6 | 10 | 2022-02-05 | 2022-02-05 |
| 7 | 12 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-01-07 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xjhqMeNn)

Comment: Why not just using `lead()`? Could be sooo much simpler and no GROUP BY required.

Comment: i added a solution without Lead and GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to filter most recent rows and [`LEAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) for `last_sale`. Use [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) for the case when no `last_sale` exists:

```
with cte as (
  select
    ID_sale,
    sales_person,
    sale_date as recent_sale,
    lead(sale_date) over w as last_sale,
    row_number() over w as rn
  from sales
  window w as (partition by sales_person order by sale_date desc)
)
select 
  ID_sale,
  sales_person,
  recent_sale,
  coalesce(last_sale, recent_sale) as last_sale
from cte
where rn = 1
order by ID_sale;
```

For older versions that don't support window function (like `ROW_NUMBER()` and `LEAD()`) you can use correlated (by `sales_person`) subqueries for last_sale and for the recent row filter in the WHERE clause:

```
select 
  s.ID_sale,
  s.sales_person,
  s.sale_date as recent_sale,
  coalesce((
    select
    max(sale_date)
    from sales s2
    where s2.sales_person = s.sales_person
      and s2.sale_date    < s.sale_date
  ), s.sale_date) as last_sale
from sales s
where sale_date = (
  select max(sale_date)
  from sales s1
  where s1.sales_person = s.sales_person
)
order by ID_sale;
```

Comment: this needs two window functions and would be slower

Comment: @nbk Slower than what?

Answer (score 0):

Not as efficient as a window function, but simpler and portable:

```sql
select max(t1.ID_sale), t1.sales_person, t1.recent_sale, max(t2.recent_sale) as last_sale
from mytable t1
left join mytable t2 on t2.sales_person = t1.sales_person
and t2.ID_sale < t1.ID_sale
group by 2, 3
```

Unless you have 100's of millions of sales, this will perform OK if you have an index on sales_person.